# How to install openstack in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: openstack

I would like to install Openstack Havana in my system(14.04).

I have tried this [link](http://fosshelp.blogspot.in/2014/02/devstack-how-to-install-stable.html). `I have`clone` devstack by,

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git -b stable/havana
```

I can saw in folder `devstack`,

```
arul@arul-PC:~/openstack/devstack$ ls
AUTHORS   exerciserc   extras.d   HACKING.rst  openrc           run_tests.sh  stack.sh  unstack.sh
clean.sh  exercises    files      lib          README.md        samples       tests
```

eucarc    exercise.sh  functions  LICENSE      rejoin-stack.sh  stackrc       tools

When I try,

```
arul@arul-PC:~/openstack/devstack$ ./stack.sh
```

I got response as,

```
WARNING: this script has not been tested on trusty
[Call Trace]
./stack.sh:137:die
[ERROR] ./stack.sh:137 If you wish to run this script anyway run with FORCE=yes
```

Where I can get 'openstack' tested with `trusty`?

---

**EDIT**

When I tried to install `icehouse` using,

```
arul@arul-PC:~$ sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:icehouse
```

I got response as,

```
Ubuntu Cloud Archive for Openstack icehouse
More info: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

cloud-archive only supported on precise
```

Answer (score 2):

You are running currently the newest version of Ubuntu - Trusty (14.04), however version of OpenStack you are trying to install on it is Havana, but Trusty was build in mind to support newest OpenStack IceHouse. Look at the picture below to see release cycles:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive/

So you have several options. Go with Ubuntu 12.04 if you want to use DevStack, which currently supports:

> Only Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise), Fedora 20 and CentOS/RHEL 6.5 are documented here. OpenStack also runs and is packaged on other flavors of Linux such as OpenSUSE and Debian.

you can follow simple steps to deploy OpenStack Havana on Ubuntu Precise with DevStack here:

[http://devstack.org/](http://devstack.org)

Or (and I really encourage you to try, if you find it interesting) to deploy OpenStack Havana on Trusty using official guide:

http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/apt/content/

It might seem a bit more complicated, but trust me you will learn a lot of stuff along the way! And it works (personal experience : ) ).

Have fun!

Comment: Mirantis Fuel - another relatively easy way to install OpenStack I forgot to mention. It's free to check out: https://software.mirantis.com/

Comment: please have a look, I edit my question...

Answer (score 0):

For newer Openstack deployments on Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) please follow the installation instructions found at:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

This will provide you with a fully deployed Openstack currently running Juno.